# gitlab - sidekiq wont work correctly

Tags: git, gitlab, freebsd, sidekiq, dedicated

1 -2 hours ago i tried to install gitlab on my FreeBSD Dedicated-Server.
Until i done i checked if all is running with this command:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

I got the following output:
Checking GitLab Shell ...

```
GitLab Shell version >= 3.2.1 ? ... OK (3.2.1)
Repo base directory exists?
default... yes
Repo storage directories are symlinks?
default... no
Repo paths owned by git:git?
default... yes
Repo paths access is drwxrws---?
default... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects
Running /usr/home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files:
/usr/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Send ping to redis server: gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... no
Try fixing it:
sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production bin/background_jobs start
For more information see:
doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
see log/sidekiq.log for possible errors
Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Reply by email ...

Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Reply by email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Git configured with autocrlf=input? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Uploads directory setup correctly? ... skipped (no tmp uploads folder yet)
Init script exists? ... no
Try fixing it:
Install the init script
For more information see:
doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Init script up-to-date? ... can't check because of previous errors
projects have namespace: ... can't check, you have no projects
Redis version >= 2.8.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.1.0 ? ... yes (2.2.6)
Your git bin path is "/usr/local/bin/git"
Git version >= 2.7.3 ? ... yes (2.11.0)
Active users: 1
Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

After i read this i started with checking if the init script exists, i found it under "/usr/local/etc/rc.d/" named "gitlab". Then i tried the command at the point "try fixing it": sudo -u git -H RAILS_ENV=production bin/background_jobs start
No output... so i running the first command again and i got the same output. Then i tried to install the init script again with the tutorial from the installation.md. After all i checked again and again the same output... then i read the sidekiq.log:

```
2017-02-20T19:18:22.576Z 18632 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Shutting down
2017-02-20T19:18:22.576Z 18632 TID-7yu1pks INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2017-02-20T19:18:22.577Z 18632 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Terminating quiet workers
2017-02-20T19:18:22.577Z 18632 TID-7yylx3s INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2017-02-20T19:18:23.109Z 18632 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Pausing to allow workers to finish...
2017-02-20T19:18:25.172Z 18632 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Bye!
Sidekiq shut down gracefully.
2017-02-20T19:18:34.957Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.1.4 with redis options {:url=>"unix:/usr/local/var/run/redis/redis.sock", :namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}
2017-02-20T19:18:34.965Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: stuck_ci_builds_worker
2017-02-20T19:18:34.967Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: expire_build_artifacts_worker
2017-02-20T19:18:34.971Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: repository_check_worker
2017-02-20T19:18:34.973Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: admin_email_worker
2017-02-20T19:18:34.975Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: repository_archive_cache_worker
2017-02-20T19:18:34.977Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: import_export_project_cleanup_worker
2017-02-20T19:18:38.199Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Running in ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [amd64-freebsd11]
2017-02-20T19:18:38.199Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2017-02-20T19:18:38.199Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
```

I got no idea what to do... i tried to search on google but i found nothing.

Here some detail about my Server:
Dedicated Server
32 GB Ram
3TB HDD
Intel Core i7-3770
FreeBSD 11 64-bit

I hope i you have enougth information to help me!
I know my english is not the best, i tryed my best. =)

Best regards,
Tycan

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, Sidekiq seems to have booted fine according to the logs?  `2017-02-20T19:18:34.957Z 18898 TID-7whi9lg INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.1.4 with redis options {:url=>"unix:/usr/local/var/run/redis/redis.sock", :namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}`

Comment: Yes its booted, but if I check git you can see:
Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... no

And then the help howto fix it, but this dosnt work.